# Home network traffic dropping under load

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a small home network with several devices connected through both wifi and ethernet (Dlink powerline).  I frequently have problems where under load (torrents, or syncing plex movies to an ipad) the network dies.

I've tested that with a hard ethernet link from the router (ATT NVG589) the internet seems to be always up.  What makes things interesting is that on my desktop PC running windows 10, I have both the powerline and a wifi usb stick connected.  Whenever one of them fails, I can switch to the other in adapter settings and I'm back online. And then after a few minutes, I can switch between both and they are good.  Haven't seen a scenario yet where both are dead when router internet connection is okay.

Also of note is that when the network is down, it's down for all devices connected to that network.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: You simply have a fixed, finite amount of bandwidth, and if it is being used by torrents, etc. there isn't much or any left over for whatever else you want to do.

Comment: The network is still down even after I stop all torrents, etc.  but they do come back up after a few minutes.   Maybe I need to set some sort of QoS settings on my router?